# Where is xmlns attribute defined?

Tags: xml, xml-namespaces

I know that this is correct XML

```
<Data xmlns="http://w3.schools.com">
  <One>Data1</One>
</Data>
```

`xmlns` is an attribute and using the above syntax means all nodes belong to the namespace in double quotes. What I can't understand is where is `xmlns` attribute defined?

Comment: Well I have gone through the answers in stack overflow. I have understood that attribute is actually used to bind a namespace in xml. However my question from where does this attribute available in every xml file. From what i have learnt that attribute when having a specific meaning or purpose is binded to a namespace and can be used only when that namespace is defined in xml file

Comment: Then you should notice *"URI that needs to be unique so as to indicate that it is a separate namespace from others and any potential duplicate tags will therefore be interpreted correctly. **So the URI will often point to nothing**."*

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "where is xmlns defined", but the spec is here: https://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml-names-20060816/

Comment: Hi Wayne, the abstract reads like this "XML namespaces provide a simple method for qualifying element and attribute names used in Extensible Markup Language documents by associating them with namespaces identified by URI references." My question is if xmlns is an attribute then where is it defined?? Which namespace contains that attribute??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [***Namespaces in XML 1.0 W3C Recommendation***](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/) for the definitions of both the `xmlns` attribute and `xmlns:` prefix.

**Summary of reasons to use `xmlns`:**

- Use `xmlns` *as an attribute* to define an XML namespace, which is a
  naming standard designed to allow parties to independently define
  vocabularies of element and attribute names while avoiding naming
  collisions.
- Use `xmlns:` *as a prefix* to define a custom prefix by which an XML
  namespace value can be referenced by shorthand.

### Attribute `xmlns`

The **attribute `xmlns`** is a [***reserved attribute***](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#ns-decl) and is [defined as follows](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#NT-DefaultAttName):

> `DefaultAttName ::= 'xmlns'`

### Prefix `xmlns:`

The **prefix `xmlns:`** is a [***reserved prefix***](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#ns-decl) and [defined as follows](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#NT-PrefixedAttName):

> `[2] PrefixedAttName ::= 'xmlns:' NCName`

See also [Namespace constraint: Reserved Prefixes and Namespace Names](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#xmlReserved)

> The prefix **xmlns** is used only to declare namespace bindings and is by
>   definition bound to the namespace name http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/.
>   It MUST NOT be declared . Other prefixes MUST NOT be bound to this
>   namespace name, and it MUST NOT be declared as the default namespace.
>   Element names MUST NOT have the prefix xmlns.

### Reference from [XML Recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/)

**[2.3 Common Syntactic Constructs](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-common-syn)**

> **Note:**
>
> The Namespaces in XML Recommendation [[XML Names](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#xml-names)] assigns a meaning to
>   names containing colon characters. Therefore, authors should not use
>   the colon in XML names except for namespace purposes, but XML
>   processors must accept the colon as a name character.